# How do I update the display when a factory is called from a child controller

Tags: angularjs

Let's assume the following HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  {{currentValue}}
  <div ng-controller="myInnerController">
    <button ng-click="toggleValue()">
      Click me
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'valueFactory', function($scope, valueFactory) {
    $scope.currentValue = valueFactory.getValue();
  }]);

app.controller('myInnerController', ['$scope', 'valueFactory', function($scope, valueFactory) {
  $scope.toggleValue = function() {
      valueFactory.toggleValue();
    };
}]);

app.factory('valueFactory', function() {
  var value = false;

  var service = {
    getValue: function() {
      return value;
    },
    toggleValue: function() {
      value = !value;
      console.log(value);
    }
  };

  return service;
});
```

Currently, `currentValue` will always display false. It should change every time the "click me" button is pressed.

I have tried a few things such as updating `$scope.currentValue` inside of the inner controller, adding a watch to the parent controller. Nothing I have tried works.

So how do I impact `currentValue` by calling the factory in the child controller?

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7cvtcLrc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning `boolean` type value.

Value type won't keep any bindings.

**`function`**,**`object`**,**`array`**,**`date`** are reference type.

This type assignment will keep reference.

Try like this

JS

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'valueFactory', function($scope, valueFactory) {
  $scope.valueFactory = valueFactory;

}]);
```

HTML

```
{{valueFactory.getValue()}}
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/m695u7gz/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks mate. I'm glad it was something small I missed.

Answer (score 0):

I am by far no expert but it looks like you are returning value from the getvalue function without applying the toggle. I think the return needs to be after the toggle function.